# Gradle: How to allow only specific transitive dependency

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, dependency-management, transitive-dependency

I would like to globally disable all transitive dependencies. I am using the following and it works fine.

```
configurations.all {
    transitive = false
}
```

Problem is that I need to allow transitive dependencies for one specific dependency. Is there a way to do this?

I tried variations of the following but with no success.

```
compile("my:dep:xxx") {
    transitive = true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that :

```
configurations.all {
    dependencies.matching { it.group != 'my' || it.name != 'dep' }.all {
        transitive = false
    }
}
```